# App not listed in authorized apps in google account

Tags: google-oauth

When i try get access token via oauth (oauth screen with Allow button) on my local machine it works, but when i do the same on test server: i get oauth screen, i press allow and it's redirects to callback uri with code, and then app asking for token (i use PHP lib):

`$client->authenticate($request->get('code'));
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken());`

and i get null in response and application does not get authorized and it's not in authorized apps in google account.

I've checked redirect URLs listed in Google APIs - everything matches!
And i don't get any errors from google, it's just redirects to callback url and not adds application to authorized apps list.

But it works on local with same credentials. Any one can help me and guide where the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I did not set redirect url before $client->authenticate($request->get('code'));